# jQuery UI - adding tabs tutorial need explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm having trouble understanding a certain part of the jQuery UI tabs tutorial. Specifically this part `#{href}'>#{label}` What is it doing/what does it mean?

Full code:

```
$(function () {
    var tabTitle = $("#tab_title"),
      tabContent = $("#tab_content"),
      tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
      tabCounter = 3;

    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

    // modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback reseting the form inside
    var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Add: function () {
          addTab();
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      close: function () {
        form[0].reset();
      }
    });

    // addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
    var form = dialog.find("form").submit(function (event) {
      addTab();
      dialog.dialog("close");
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    // actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
    function addTab() {
      var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
        tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

      tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
      tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
      tabs.tabs("refresh");
      tabCounter++;
    }

    // addTab button: just opens the dialog
    $("#add_tab")
      .button()
      .click(function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
      });

    // close icon: removing the tab on click
    tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function () {
      var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
      $("#" + panelId).remove();
      tabs.tabs("refresh");
    });

    tabs.bind("keyup", function (event) {
      if (event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE) {
        var panelId = tabs.find(".ui-tabs-active").remove().attr("aria-controls");
        $("#" + panelId).remove();
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, #{href} and #{label} as well as #tab_title and #tab_content are placeholders. These placeholders are replaced with the real content.

The jQuery UI tutorial holds some LI elements that will become the tabs afterwards:

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
```

You can match the content of href="" to the #{href} placeholder and the content of the A element will be inserted into the corresponding #{label}

The href-part even names the div-id that will contain the content.

```
<div id="tabs-1">
  <p>Proin elit arcu, [... ]tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
```

The div with the id "tabs-1" will be read as the content for tab "#tabs-1". Inside the template, this content will be used in place of #tab_content.

Answer (score 3):

You are putting this into a string:

```
<a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a>
```

And later on, you're taking that string and doing this with it:

```
tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)
```

So what you're doing is replacing the `{href}` and `{label}` characters in the original string with the actual link and text for the `<a>` tag.